# WordPress - Display Random Number Between 190-250

Tags: php, wordpress, random

Does anyone know of a way to display a random number between 190-250 inside a specific page?

For example:
Today I had *Display Random Number* Coffees.

Comment: Have you tried any of the random number functions in php??

Comment: if _inside a specific page_, then I would suggest you to use inline JavaScript instead, or if possible, along with some jQuery.

Comment: Have you searched for any plugin for a shortcode? Even if there was none, it would take  5 minutes to make a plugin to do it.

Comment: It depends specifically WHERE in the post or page  you want to display it and HOW .  Is it always the same string ? or was it an example ? I can think of maybe 5 or 6 different ways , from jQuery to Filters to pure PHP - all depend on the above ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would accomplish this is with a shortcode, like this:

```
function na_random_number_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $post;

    $args = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'min'  => 190,
            'max' => 250,
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'hours' => 24
        ),
        $atts, 'random_number'
    );

    // Use transient to store the random number temporarily 
    if ( false === ( $random_number = get_transient( 'random_number_'.$args['id'] ) ) ) {
        $random_number = mt_rand( (int) $args['min'], (int) $args['max'] );
        set_transient( 'random_number_'.$args['id'], $random_number, HOUR_IN_SECONDS * $args['hours'] );
    }

    return $random_number;
}
add_shortcode( 'random_number', 'na_random_number_shortcode' );
```

Putting that code in your theme's functions.php file would allow you to enter

> "Today I had [random_number] Coffees."

and display a random number between 190 and 250.

It's also flexible; you can do something like `[random_number min="1" max="10"]` to get a random number between 1 and 10.

By default, it will remember the random number for 24 hours. You can change this by passing in the "hours" attribute, like: `[random_number hours="12"]`

If you have more than one of these on a page, and you want the numbers to be different, you have to give each one a unique id. So if you had two of them, you could do: `[random_number id="1"]` and `[random_number id="2"]`

Comment: great! Thank you so much!
Is it possible to make the new number displayed after 24 hours? So every 24 hours a new random number is shown?

Comment: Yes, but would there ever be more than 1 of these on a page? My solution would depend on that answer.

Comment: I updated the code so it will remember for 24 hours, using transients. Transients are perfect for this because they are meant to storing things temporarily. If need more than 1 on a page, just give them unique IDs.

Comment: Hey Nate, unfortunately the hours store does not work. After using the code and testing it doesn't seem to change after a certain amount of time. Is there something missing by any chance? Many thanks for your time and effort by the way I really appreciate it.

Comment: @squidg I just tested it by changing the default hours from "24" to "1", and then put the shortcode on a page. When I loaded the page, I got 226. It stayed 226 even when I reloaded. Then, I waited an hour and reloaded again and got a new number, 247.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the PHP `rand` function in the page where you want it:

```
echo(rand(190,250));
```